# Running a Pig script in Spring

Tags: spring, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am new to Spring framework and I need some help in running a Pig Script.

I have created a Pig Script which I need to integrate with Spring Framework. How to do that ? Please help me in this issue. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/pig.html ?
what exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: I have read that.  I am new to Spring framework so I need to know is there any other maven should I use before trying the thing mentioned in the above article. Please help me to understand this . Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a step by step procedure of running a pig script using Spring ?